# Bootstrap Modal Shifts Website Vertically on Close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Upon closing a Bootstrap modal, if the full button is not in view, it will shift the website. How do you make it so that no matter where you are, when the modal closes the website stays where it is?

As this occurs on Bootstrap's own webpage, it is not related to my personal code. See video for example:

https://streamable.com/dmlh4

On my website I am making the modal button a large image, which greatly increases the shift upon close.

Comment: Could you place an array of invisible buttons over the image so that the one the user clicks on is fully on screen and so the shift up isn't required? Aplogies, I don't know enough about the required API to actually post some example code.

Comment: Thanks Todd. That could be a viable work-around but I would like to find a more pointed solution.